# Переменные с _ в python

Tags: python

Смотрю примеры кода на различных сайтах и часто вижу переменные (или я не понимаю, что это) с вот таким символом "_". Например: _f или с двумя __. Гуглить не знаю по какому ключевому слову.
Пример кода:

```
def run_once(f):
"""
>>> @run_once
... def foo(n): return n + 1

>>> foo(7)
8

>>> foo(0)
8
"""
def _f(*args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(_f, "_retval"):
        _f._retval = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _f._retval
return _f


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: для поисковика можно использовать: "соглашения об именах", "naming conventions" ключевые слова.

Comment: кстати, `help('_')` работает.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Имя с одним подчёркиванием `_name` - по общему соглашению используется как аналог `protected`, защищённого имени в других языках. В других языках такое имя могут использовать только наследники класса. В питоне же это просто соглашение.
2. Имя с двумя подчёркиваниями `__name` является аналогом `private` (в питоне псевдоприватное), имя только для внутреннего использования внутри модуля или класса. У таких имён есть специальная защита, и обратиться к нему снаружи можно только зная класс, в котором этот атрибут определен.
3. Имена с двумя подчёркиваниями с двух сторон имени `__name__` являются "магическими" методами, реализующими некоторую функциональность языка.

Comment: Простите, что ?

Comment: Ну ты прав. Только поправлять было не обязательно. В каждое сообщение кто-то залазит и что-то правит. У вас тут прямо соревнования какие-то.

Answer (score 6):

Советую почитать [официальную документацию](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Имена, которые начинаются с одного подчёркивания (`_variable`), предназначены для внутреннего использования.

Те же имена, которые **начинаются и заканчиваются** на двойное подчёркивание (`__init__`), обычно являются уже встроенными и только переопределяются.

Answer (score -5):

Просто используется чтобы переменная _f != f. Тоесть переменные похожи, но разные. Это достаточно популярный метод в python

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?